# mat-side-nav bar does not stretch to the entire width of the window

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-sidenav

I am currently at intermediate level at understanding Angular (Angular - Version 5). I have been trying to build a sample application of my own and I also intend to use the angular material components for the UX.

When I use mat-side-nav, the navigation content does not stretch to the entire browser/window height. Instead it just extends to a very minimal height.

Following is the piece of code that I am currently have in my project.

Header.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="snav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <H3 style="color:white;" class="navbar-brand">Agile Center</H3>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>dashboard</mat-icon></button>
    <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>settings</mat-icon></button>
    <span [hidden]="isUserLoggedIn">
        <!--<a mat-button routerLink="." style="color:white">Logout</a> -->
        <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>power_settings_new</mat-icon></button>
    </span>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav #snav mode="over" fixedTopGap="56">
      <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="backlog">Backlog</a>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink=".">Active Sprints</a>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink=".">Releases</a>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink=".">Reports</a>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink=".">Issues</a>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink=".">Administration</a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

Header.component.css

```
.example-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 5px;
}

.example-sidenav-container {
    /* When the sidenav is not fixed, stretch the sidenav container to fill the available space. This
       causes `<mat-sidenav-content>` to act as our scrolling element for desktop layouts. */
    flex: 1;
}

.example-spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

No code yet in header.component.ts

Code in app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <app-header></app-header>
</div>
```

Screenshot of the side navigation bar

[image]

Can anyone help where I am going wrong here?

Thanks to one and all!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `.example-container` element in that HTML, but you've got a CSS class for it

Comment: looks fine to me on screenshot

Comment: @user184994 - Thanks for pointing out. I guess i did not see the .example-container element was not added to the div tag. It worked after i added that class to the div tag.